# How to Add LOCAL_QUORUM consistency on Cassandra Cluster side

Tags: cassandra, datastax

There is any option to add default consistency level LOCAL_QUORUM to side or cassandra.ymal file.

Answer (score 1):

Using JAVA :

```
    QueryOptions option = new QueryOptions();
    option.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_QUORUM);
    Cluster.Builder clusterBuilder = Cluster.builder().withQueryOptions(option);
```